# How to attach something like an after_commit callback to an Ecto transaction?

Tags: elixir, ecto

Is there a way to attach a callback to an Ecto transaction that is invoked after the transaction has been committed? I'm looking for something akin to [ActiveRecord's `after_commit`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#transaction-callbacks).

The use case I'm working with is initiating side effects after an operation is performed. For example, in the code below, I want to initiate side effects in `App.ServiceB.run/0`, but since it's getting called in the context of a transaction started by the caller, I can't guarantee the operation won't be rolled back.

```
defmodule App.ServiceA do
  alias App.Repo

  def run() do
    App.Repo.transaction(fn ->
      with {:ok, _} <- ServiceB.run(),
           {:ok, entity} <- {:error, :foo}
      do
         {:ok, entity}
      else
        {:error, reason} -> Repo.rollback(reason)
      end
    end)
  end
end

defmodule App.ServiceB do
  def run() do
    with {:ok, entity} <- Repo.insert(create_changeset()) do
      # initiate side effects
      {:ok, entity}
    end
  end

  defp create_changeset() do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Is there anything built into Ecto I should use? Are there any libraries that help with this? Should I be structuring the code differently to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as an after commit hook in Ecto. But the transaction call returns `{:ok, result}` or `{:error, message}`, so you can match on the return value like this:

```
def run() do
  with {:ok, result} <- App.Repo.transaction(fn ->
    with {:ok, _} <- ServiceB.run(),
         {:ok, entity} <- {:error, :foo} do
      {:ok, entity}
    else
      {:error, reason} -> Repo.rollback(reason)
    end
  end) do
    # after commit (only if it succeeded)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Also the answer by @smallbutton-com is absolutely correct, we usually use [`Ecto.Multi`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html?) for this kind of task. It is kinda more robust than the bare transaction because it checks changesets before starting the transaction, etc.

For your use case, the code would look kinda

```rb
defmodule SeveralServies do
  alias Ecto.Multi

  def run(foo, params) do
    Multi.new
    |> Multi.update(:serviceB, ServiceB.foo_changeset(foo, params))
    |> Multi.insert(:serviceC, ServiceC.foo_changeset(foo, params))
  end
end
```

And later:

```rb
case Repo.transaction(SeveralServices.run(foo, params)) do
  {:ok, result} -> SeveralServices.after_commit(result)
  _ -> :error
end
```